# PyTorch vs. Tensorflow Fold

Tags: python, deep-learning, tensorflow, pytorch

Both [PyTorch](https://github.com/hughperkins/pytorch) and [Tensorflow Fold](https://github.com/tensorflow/fold) are deep learning frameworks meant to deal with situations where the input data has non-uniform length or dimensions (that is, situations where dynamic graphs are useful or needed).

I would like to know how they compare, in the sense of paradigms they rely on (e.g. dynamic batching) and their implications, things that can/cannot be implemented in each one, weaknesses/strengths, etc.

I intend to use this info to choose one of them to start exploring dynamic computation graphs, but I have no specific task in mind.

Note 1: other dynamic computation graph frameworks like [DyNet](https://github.com/clab/dynet) or [Chainer](https://github.com/pfnet/chainer) are also welcome in the comparison, but I'd like to focus on PyTorch and Tensorflow Fold because I think they are/will be the most used ones.

Note 2: I have found [this hackernews thread on PyTorch](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=13428098) with some sparse info, but  not much.

Note 3: Another relevant [hackernews thread](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=13591578), about Tensorflow Fold, that contains some info about how they compare.

Note 4: relevant [Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/MachineLearning/comments/5sn987/n_announcing_tensorflow_fold_deep_learning_with/).

Note 5: [relevant bug in Tensorflow Fold's github](https://github.com/tensorflow/fold/issues/8) that identifies an important limitation: impossibility to do conditional branching during evaluation.

Note 6: [discussion on pytorch forum](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/about-the-variable-length-input-in-rnn-scenario/345) about variable length inputs in relation to the algorithms used (e.g. dynamic batching).

Comment: You can also add [this ongoing (as of writing this comment) discussion](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/about-the-variable-length-input-in-rnn-scenario/345) by pytorch's contributors to your list of references.

Comment: I found this link very interesting and it is comparing as you asked for(about dynamic graph and using DyNet and Chainer)
https://hackernoon.com/how-is-pytorch-different-from-tensorflow-2c90f44747d6

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are a couple of good threads on Reddit right now ([here](https://www.reddit.com/r/MachineLearning/comments/5w3q74/d_so_pytorch_vs_tensorflow_whats_the_verdict_on/) and [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/MachineLearning/comments/5otdwl/d_tensorflow_vs_pytorch_why_is_dynamic_better/)).

I haven't used either of these frameworks, but from reading around and talking to users I gather that support for dynamic graphs in *PyTorch* is a 'top down design principle', whereas *TensorFlow Fold* is bolted on to the original Tensorflow framework, so if you're doing anything reasonably complicated with *Tensorflow Fold* you're probably going to end up doing a lot more hacking around than if you're using *PyTorch*.

Comment: That was pretty much my experience with trying to use Fold with convolutions over trees for the past several months. It's not mature enough to handle things like that yet. They suggest "work arounds" if you look at the  closed issues on their repo. Switching to PyTorch because Fold is so inflexible - pun intended.